# Need help to build http request for yoututbe video upload

Tags: http, youtube, youtube-api, google-api, httprequest

Let me mention it first that I am a learner at building HTTP Requests. I am trying to examine HTTP traffic and how it works. I had some luck with loging in successfully by getting the values of various tokens from the page and passing them as parameters :

GALX, dsh, and bgresponse

to :

```
https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLoginAuth
```

with parameters:

```
continue=$continue&service=youtube&dsh=$dsh&hl=en_US&GALX=$GALX&pstMsg=1&dnConn=&checkConnection=youtube:1000:1&checkedDomains=youtube&timeStmp=&secTok=&_utf8=$_utf8&bgresponse=$bgresponse&Email=$Email&Passwd=$Password&signIn=Sign in&PersistentCookie=yes&rmShown=1
```

Now I am stuck at trying to build the HTTP Request to upload a video to Youtube. Apart from the video file what parameters do I need to pass to upload a video to Youtube?

Can anyone please help me build the HTTP Request?

Any help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Praney

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use Google's [Resumable Upload](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/using_resumable_upload_protocol) guide. It shows the HTTP requests you need, with a simple example. It was enough for me to get it working, but since Friday evening I am encountering a "503 : Service Unavailable" error, which should mean the Youtube API service is having some issues (although it might be because I did something wrong).

Comment: Mate can you please share what HTTP Request did you build?
Thanks

Comment: On [another thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17922173/error-503-service-unavailable-while-trying-to-upload-a-video-with-the-youtub) I show a sample request. It works for me (I just had to remove the space in the X-Upload-Content-Length value), if you have troubles let me know which errors you get (and post the requests and response here, that will help).

Comment: I also forgot to say something about the link I gave you in my answer : delete the line `"embeddable": True,`, it gave me errors (Parse Error, if I remember well), I guess it's missing some quotes around the "True" or something.