# Error "503 : Service unavailable" while trying to upload a video with the YouTube API

Tags: youtube-api, httprequest, http-status-code-503

**Answered** :
The `X-Upload-Content-Length` value had a space in it.

**Question** :

I want to use the Youtube API to upload videos from a desktop application, in C++. I implemented the [Resumable Upload](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/using_resumable_upload_protocol), everything worked on Friday 19/07 in the afternoon, I could upload a couple of small videos, and since then I always get an error when using my app : "503 : Service Unavailable".

I found several threads treating this topic, it seems there were two solutions :

- Retry the request several times in a row
- Wait, it somehow works again after a while

Doing the same request again and again didn't solve it for me (I tried to do the request 5 times in a row, maybe I should do more requests ? How many ?). Here is a sample request and the response I get :

Request :

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/videos?uploadType=resumable&part=snippet HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: xx
Authorization: Bearer MY_ACCESS_KEY
X-GData-Key: key=MY_DEV_KEY
Content-Type: application/json
X-Upload-Content-Type: video/avi
X-Upload-Content-Length: 302 080
User-Agent: SOME_PRIVATE_STUFF
Host: www.googleapis.com
Content-Length: 167
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cache-Control: no-cache

{
"snippet": {
"title": "My video title",
"description": "This is a description of my video",
"tags": ["cool", "video", "more keywords"],
"categoryId": 22
}
}
```

Response :

```
HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable
Date: Fri, 26 Jul 2013 16:33:27 GMT
Server: HTTP Upload Server Built on Jul 21 2013 19:20:38 (1374459638)
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Thanks for any help, I really don't know what to do right now.

Comment: I see a number of things wrong with your HTTP request, but I can't tell whether it's because you just changed some details when posting it publicly or whether your original HTTP actually looked like that. The first line, for instance, should not have the `https://www.googleapis.com` after the `POST`, you don't need to set `X-GData-Key` (that's used in v2 of the API), `302 080` isn't a valid number, etc.

Comment: Thanks Jeff, I corrected the `X-Upload-Content-Length` value by removing the space, it seems to work now. I removed the `X-GData-Key` as well, and the host being written on the first line is just the way Fiddler show raw requests. Are there other things that are not correct ?

Comment: (I still don't understand why it gave me a "503 : Service Unavailable" error instead of a "400 : Bad Request" though...)

Comment: If it's working at this point then I think you're okay. Those were the main issues that I saw.